# Can neutralization be reversed?

Tags: titration

So far, maybe it's just that my course isn't advanced enough, but I have never seen anything called 'neutralization constant'.

Any such reaction involving an acid and a base will be complete no matter the strength of either reactant.

Buffer works the same way. If the reaction is reversible then the buffet is not effective.

Comment: I imagine by "neutralization constant" you mean the inverse of the autoionization constant. [For water](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-ionization_of_water) that would mean $\ce{H^+ + OH^- -> H2O},\ \ K=1.0 \times 10^{14}$. This massive constant is why even weak acids or bases completely dissociate and react when faced against a strong base or acid, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

The reverse reaction of neutralization is called hydrolysis ( X salt + H2O = acid + base )

Comment: But that's if you start with water and salt

Comment: Hmm then i guess i don't understand the question.

Comment: I tried again to understand the question hahah and i hope this time I'll help.It's not that any of these reactions will be complete and it depends on the strength of either reactant.Neutralisation between an acid and a base either of which  or both are weak will be a reversible reaction which means that it is not complete, on the other hand strong acid a bases in neutralisation will be complete and it will be a ireversible reaction.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you start with pure salt - reaction is the same.

Answer (score 0):

In general under normal conditions of temperature and pressure the reverse reaction of the neutralization is not possible because of their (acids & bases)  tendency (release of H+ ion & OH- ion) to form salt water due to which there is no any constant so called "neutralization constant"

But as for the consideration, the reverse of the neutralization reaction is called hydrolysis. In a hydrolysis reaction a salt reacts with water to yield the acid or base:
BA + H2O → HA + BOH